# NPM error while installing on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am Web developer and I wanted to convert my site into Desktop app using Electron. I tried to install npm by typing in cmd:

```
npm install;
```

and i get error that looks like:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\simel\package.json'
npm WARN simel No description
npm WARN simel No repository field.
npm WARN simel No README data
npm WARN simel No license field.
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Did you create a package.json? In which directory? Try `cd <directory of my project>` then rerun `npm install`.

Comment: It still doesn't work @Aurora0001

Comment: Did you ever initialise your project?

Comment: Never before @Aurora0001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you're in the project folder (use 'cd' to navigate to the folder), just type the command:

```
npm init
```

It will create the package.json file so you can declare in it the dependencies of your project and install them.

Comment: it created folder "node_modules" and showed this code:This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults. 

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (Test-App) @Yohanan Baruchel

Comment: ok so now you have to decide which packages do you want in your project so you can install them like this "npm install <package name>"

Comment: I already had created packages.json and added there code: {
  "name"    : "Test-App",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "main"    : "main.js" 
} what else do i have to add? @Yohanan Baruchel

Comment: nothing, Just install the dependencies of your project from the cli